# Set Status code 500

Tags: java, html, xml, jsp, jakarta-ee

I'm working on a rest API where when  post request is made by posting an XML file it should send the response 200 OK if the file is received successfully and 400 if the XML file is having any tag missing and 500 error if GET is used instead of POST. I am able to do the first two cases 200 and 400, not sure how to add 500 in the code. Am posting my code here, please suggest.

```
  if (dataFile==null) {
            try {

            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, 
    "Failed to process content of file.");
            }
            catch (IOException e1) {
                LOGGER.error("Failed to send response due to error:
   " + e1.getMessage());   
            }
        }


        else{

        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        response.addHeader("Location", getResourceUri(dataFileMetadata,   
   request).toString());
```

Comment: Could you also share the method signature?

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty unclear from your code example what you're trying to do there,
but I would guess that you're talking about something like this:

```
@POST
@Path("/some/path")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public Response post(String someXML) {
    try {
        if (isMissingTag(someXML)) {
            return Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity("error message goes here").build();
        }

        // do stuff

        return Response.ok().build();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("error message goes here", e);
        return Response.serverError().entity("error message goes here").build();
    }
}
```

You won't need to return anything if someone tries to hit your service with a GET, since you aren't publishing that as an endpoint in the first place.

I would highly suggest reading [the jersey user guide](https://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html) if you're interested in writing restful web services.